Applying a force on an object so that it hits a target in a parabolic motion
I am trying to shoot a cannonball out of a cannon in a 3D space, but the cannonball lands significantly beyond the target. I am using physics calculations to determine the initial velocity based on the launch angle and time to land.
The problem is not so complex because the only force applied in this scenario is gravity, the object has no drag. And yet for the life of me I cannot figure out what is wrong.
For my X and Z axes I am using Uniform Rectilinear Motion with the equation:
x = v0x * cos(alpha) * t + x0

where x is the position in the x axis, v0x the initial velocity (what I would like to figure out), alpha the angle, t the time to land and x0 the initial position.
For my Y axis I am using uniformly accelerated (by gravity only).
Mainly,
y = y0 + v0y * sin(alpha) * t - 1/2 gt^2

where y is the position in the y axis, y0 the initial position, v0y the initial velocity (also want to figure it out), and g is gravity force.
And yet, applying all of this results in a very wacky cannonball launch...
I have looked in many other posts, but either their requirements were not the same as mine, or they used a different equation I could barely understand.
Here is the code:
void ShootCannonball(Vector3 targetPoint, Vector3 originPoint, float T)
{
    float angle = initialAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad; // Convert to radians

    GameObject newCannonball = Instantiate(cannonballPrefab, originPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    Rigidbody rb = newCannonball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    float vox = UniformMotionX(targetPoint.x, originPoint.x, angle, T);
    float voy = AcceleratedY(targetPoint.y, originPoint.y, angle, T);
    float voz = UniformMotionZ(targetPoint.z, originPoint.z, angle, T);

    Vector3 push = new Vector3(vox, voy, voz);

    // Fire!
    rb.AddForce(push, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}    

float UniformMotionX(float target, float origin, float angle, float T)
{
    return (target - origin) / (T * Mathf.Cos(angle));
}

float AcceleratedY(float target, float origin, float angle, float T)
{
    return (target - origin + 0.5f * currentGravity * Mathf.Pow(T,2)) / (T * Mathf.Sin(angle));
}

float UniformMotionZ(float target, float origin, float angle, float T)
{
    return (target - origin) / (T * Mathf.Cos(angle));
}

A link to the problem in video format: https://imgur.com/a/8hfdvh6
Thank you for any tips you can give me, and anything else you need please ask.
In the video you can see the aim is OK, but it always overshoots it.

This falls under the heading of "easing functions".

I think your formula is wrong. If v0 is the initial velocity along the path, then v0.x = v0 * cos(alpha) and v0.y = v0 * sin(alpha). You already have v0.x and v0.y. So, don't apply sin and cos to them.

I am not sure I understand what your initial parameters are. What exactly you are given.
Let's work in 2D.
If you are given the position of the cannonball, let's call it [x0, y0], the position of the target, let's call it [x1, y1], the angle between the initial velocity and the horizontal axis Ox, say angle = a, and the time of flight T between the cannonball and the target, then I think you have too many initial parameters.
If the time of flight T is not that important to you, then keep only [x0, y0], [x1, y1], and angle = a as initial parameters. Then the time of flight can be calculated. But if you really insist on the time of flight, then you have to let go of the velocity angle.
Case 1:
Initial parameters: angle = a, [x0, y0], [x1, y1]
Equations of motion:
x = x0 + t*v*cos(a)

y = y0 + t*v*sin(a) - t*t*g/2

solve for t,v:
x1 = x0 + t*v*cos(a)

y1 = y0 + t*v*sin(a) - t*t*g/2

Solve the first equation for t:
t*v = (x1 - x0)/cos(a)

t = (x1 - x0)/(v*cos(a))

Substitute t in the second equation and solve for v:
(y1 - y0) = (x1 - x0)*sin(a)/cos(a) - g*(x1 - x0)^2/(2*v^2*cos^2(a))

g*(x1 - x0)^2/(2*v^2*cos^2(a)) = (x1 - x0)*sin(a)/cos(a) - (y1 - y0)

2*v^2*cos^2(a) / (g*(x1 - x0)^2) = 1 / ( (x1 - x0)*sin(a)/cos(a) - (y1 - y0) )

v^2 = (g*(x1 - x0)^2) / ( (x1 - x0)*sin(2*a) - 2*(y1 - y0)*cos^2(a) )

v = (x1 - x0) * sqrt( g / ( (x1 - x0)*sin(2*a) - 2*(y1 - y0)*cos^2(a) ) )

Case 2:
Given time of flight = T, [x0, y0], [x1, y1]
x = x0 + t*v
y = y0 + t*w - t*t*g/2

solve for the velocity [v, w]:
x1 = x0 + T*v
y1 = y0 + T*w - T*T*g/2

v = (x1 - x0)/T
w = (y1 + T*T*g/2 - y0)/T

speed = sqrt(v*v + w*w)
cos_angle = v/speed
sin_angle = w/speed

